# Create fake WiFi network and monitor clients

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'd like to create a WiFi network using my MacBook Pro mimicking my network at home and monitor all clients that connect. I want to do this because I lost my iPad and I think this is the only way to relocate it. I don't want any network sharing because my laptop itself also doesn't have an internet connection.

I tried `airbase-ng` but without success so far.

Comment: Your iPad should have a "find my phone" function to relocate it and/or lock it.

Comment: This won't help you find your iPad.

Comment: @LPChip That won't work. It doesn't have WiFi.

Comment: @Tyson I'm not certain if it is still in my house or stolen.

Comment: What's going to wake you IPad up and make it join?

Comment: @Tyson shouldn't it join automatically?